My Google Docs and Google Slides Top Menu Bars are quite zoomed out and aren't getting fixed using the commands (Ctrl plus + or Command plus +)
I've noticed that the top menu bars in my Google Docs and Google Slides are quite zoomed out:


I've even tried zooming in using the command Command + + (or Ctrl + + for Windows/Linux), but it still remains the same. On Google Docs, it even shows 100% as the zoom level.
P.S. I'm not sure if this is an OS-specific problem. I'm facing this issue on a Mac (with an Apple M2 chip and macOS 14.6.1 (23G93)), as well as on both Brave and Safari browsers.
Edit: I already followed what’s mentioned in the answers of this post, but nothing worked out. That’s why, I decided to post this question (more detailed and comprehensive than the one given in the post), along with the solution that worked for me.

This is a duplicate of the target question.  In your screenshots the zoom setting for Slides is "Fit Width" and for Docs it's "100%" while the applications' menus are shrunk in spite of this, and no changes to the apps' zoom settings also change the menu sizes. I would typically encourage you to improve an existing answer on the target question, or add your own, however this existing answer addresses and solves the problem while yours does not appear to do that.

Thanks for the clarification, @Blindspots! But, the existing answer does not solve the problem. Increasing or decreasing the browser zoom level, as mentioned, does not affect the toolbar size in either Docs or Slides. What works is adjusting the browser zoom level on Google Sheets, as this not only affects the toolbar size in Sheets itself but also in other apps like Docs and Slides. To be honest, this seems to be a glitch in the applications.

This has nothing to do with the zoom level in the Google apps. ie. "browser zoom level on Google Sheet" is misleading. It should be simply "browser zoom level"  Please note that the alternative to KB shortcuts noted in the answer ("settings from the browser 3 dots menu at the top left or right (depending on your setup))" helps explain the point I'm making.  The questions are dupes even if the answer (while correct) didn't help you.  I will improve the OP's answer to help avoid confusion for future visitors.

I have updated the OP's answer to avoid future confusion.  If it can be further improved you can suggest edits or comment on it, or add a new answer if you feel it is warranted. Be well!

Upon closer inspection, I observed that I had explicitly zoomed out on Google Sheets to 50%, which was affecting the zoom levels of the top menu bars in both Google Docs and Google Slides.

When I changed the zoom level of Google Sheets back to 100%, the zoom levels of the top menu bars in Google Docs and Google Slides were fixed as well.
Whatever zoom level you set for Google Slides will also apply to the zoom levels of the top menu bars in both Google Docs and Google Slides.
Here’s a screen recording to demonstrate the same: https://youtu.be/XFxf0iVg0ck.

You may wish to add your answer to the existing question, however FYI: 1. Changing Sheets zoom settings has no impact on the menu sizing in Sheets. 2.  Sheets zoom settings do not affect Docs or Slides zoom settings (as suggested). 3. The zoom settings of the Google apps are not factors In the problem, and most other Google/non-Google web pages would exhibit similar behavior. 4. The issue begins and ends with the web browser's zoom settings and the existing answer explains and documents it well so you may wish to try that first.
